# Predicting outcomes

Tags: prediction, predict

what are some other methods to predict an outcome other than KNN (K- Nearest Neighbor), Logistic Regression, Random forest , Bagging & boosting for any predicting problem ?

I just wanted to know if there are other methods

Comment: what about neural network? there's a lot of variation of NN

Answer (score 0):

The term I believe you are looking for is Supervised Learning (SL) which can be broken down into 2 categories.

1. Classification
2. Regression

The difference between them is about the variable you are trying to predict; is it discrete or continuous? Most prediction algorithms can be switched between these 2 options pretty easily. For a decent list of options check out `SKLearn's` [Supervised Learning](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/supervised_learning.html#supervised-learning) list of options. While it is not exhaustive it will definitely give you a good start.